# Explicit template specialization - multiple definitions

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors, explicit-specialization

I have done explicit specializations before, I just can't figure out why this does not work:

**StringUtils.hpp**

```
#ifndef AYC_STRINGUTILS_HPP
#define AYC_STRINGUTILS_HPP

#include <string>

class StringUtils {
public:
    template <typename T>
    static std::string toString(const T& t);
};

#include "StringUtils.tpp"

#endif //AYC_STRINGUTILS_HPP
```

**StringUtils.tpp**

```
#include "StringUtils.hpp"

template<typename T>
std::string StringUtils::toString(const T& t) {
    return std::to_string(t);
}

template<>
std::string StringUtils::toString<std::string>(const std::string& t) {
    return t;
}
```

The errors I get are linker errors complaining about multiple definitions of the function `toString`.

Many files in the project use `#include "StringUtils.hpp"`.

How can I try to fix this error? Is something wrong in the class `StringUtils`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the solution provided in the [answer by Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53660677/434551), you can declare the specialization in the .hpp/.tpp file and define it in a .cpp file.

StringUtils.hpp file:

```
#ifndef AYC_STRINGUTILS_HPP
#define AYC_STRINGUTILS_HPP

#include <string>

class StringUtils {
public:
    template <typename T>
    static std::string toString(const T& t);
};

// Generic implementation.
template<typename T>
std::string StringUtils::toString(const T& t) {
    return std::to_string(t);
}

// Declation of the specialization.
template<>
std::string StringUtils::toString<std::string>(const std::string& t);

#endif //AYC_STRINGUTILS_HPP
```

StringUtils.cpp file:

```
#include "StringUtils.hpp"

// Definition of the specialization.
template<>
std::string StringUtils::toString<std::string>(const std::string& t) {
    return t;
}
```

Test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "StringUtils.hpp"

int main()
{
   std::string a("test");
   std::cout << StringUtils::toString(a) << std::endl;
   std::cout << StringUtils::toString(10) << std::endl;
}
```

Output of the test program:

```
test
10
```

Comment: Wow, great answer! This is a little bit more of what I was looking for (my style). The `inline` version seems kind-of hackish, and the function would get copied to all translation units where it is required, so.. Thanks!

Comment: @anddero, glad I was able to help.

Comment: Thanks. This is elegant... exactly what I was looking to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

An explicit (full) specialization of a function template is subject to the one-definition rule, so `StringUtils::toString<std::string>` must not be defined in multiple translation units. You can solve this problem by declaring it `inline`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Although I don't quite understand *why*, yes, this fixed my error :)

Comment: @anddero because an inline function is allowed to be defined in multiple translation units

Answer (score 0):

Template function specialization is almost always the wrong  answer.

Classes are poor namespaces.

Simply overload instead of specialize.

```
namespace StringUtils {
  template <typename T>
  std::string toString(const T& t){
    using std::to_string;
    return to_string(t);
  }
  inline std::string toString(std::string s){ return std::move(s); }
}
```

overload resolution does what you want, and it permits efficient signature variation (like above, where I take `s` by-value, which could avoid an extra heap allocation).

Also note I enabled ADL extension of `to_string` for custom classes.  Simply overload `to_steing(X)` in `X`'s namespace and `StringUtils::toString(X)` finds it.

---

Your immediate problem is you need to mark the specialization `inline`.